# I'm using win32com to convert a xlsx (excel file) to pdf, but I want to fit the size of the sheet to the pdf page

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pdf, win32com

I'm using win32com for converting a xlsx file to pdf, but the page is saved cropped halfway, this is my code

```
from win32com import client
xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path+'excel_file.xlsx')
ws = books.Worksheets[0]
ws.Visible = 1
ws.PageSetup.Orientation = 2 
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path+'pdf_file.pdf')
books.Close(True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to Page Layout ribbon -> "Scale to fit" group -> select 1 page for width and 1 page for height